# How can I install lua5.3 for Centos7

Tags: makefile, lua, cmake, centos7

Good day,
I really spent almost all after-noon looking to install lua5.3 **on Centos 7**.
I mostly found information to install Lua5.1 but we really need a version 5.2 or 5.3.

If I found information for 5.3, it was not for Centos.

Until now, the best I could do, is to download the source version from lua web site
[enter link description here](https://www.lua.org/download.html)
But I still can not install it.

Here are my steps, may be you can help to continue

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.4.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.3.4.tar.gz
cd lua-5.3.4
make linux test
```

The problem, from that point how can I install it.

I tried

```
make
```

and

```
make linux
```

make linux make me a fatal error

> [root@pc6 lua-5.3.4]# make linux cd src && make linux make[1](https://www.lua.org/download.html):
>   Entering directory `/root/install-package/lua-5.3.4/src' make all
>   SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline" make[2]:
>   Entering directory`/root/install-package/lua-5.3.4/src' gcc
>   -std=gnu99 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_2 -DLUA_USE_LINUX    -c -o lua.o lua.c lua.c:82:31: fatal error: readline/readline.h: No such
>   file or directory  #include 
>                                  ^ compilation terminated. make[2]: *** [lua.o] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/install-package/lua-5.3.4/src' make[1]: *** [linux] Error 2
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/install-package/lua-5.3.4/src' make:
>   *** [linux] Error 2

So what do you suggest me to do. Centos 7 has been istalled today. May do I miss to install a dependent a library?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 4):

The download page which you mention says:

> There are [detailed instructions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html) in the package

This link points to the [README](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/readme.html), which says:

> If you're running Linux and get compilation errors, make sure you have installed the readline development package (which is probably named libreadline-dev or readline-devel).

If you don't want to install *readline*, try `make posix` or `make posix MYCFLAGS=-DLUA_USE_DLOPEN MYLIBS=-ldl` instead. You may need to do `make clean` first.

Comment: Thank a lot. That help!!! I installed #yum install readline-devel and then #make linux, and then #make linux install. It's now installed. Thank

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling lazy, the [IUS repo](https://ius.io/) has prebuilt packages of `lua5.3` for `el7` under the name `lua53u` (`u` presumably stands for "update") (and `lua53u-devel`, etc, depending on what you need).

Simply enable the repo and then install:

```sh
# enable repos
yum install -y epel-release https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
# install
yum install -y lua53u
```